# Dynamic/calculated field in ArcGIS Pro via Arcade expression?

Tags: arcgis-pro, expression, dynamic, calculate-values, arcade

In an ESRI video called [Getting to Know Arcade](https://youtu.be/jAxisgj9yr8?t=326), the presenter states that dynamic/calculated fields are possible via Arcade expressions.

> How many of you have ever been in a
> situation where you had a dataset ... where you needed a new column of data because you wanted to have [calculated values]?
>
> ...But you had to go and make a new column and calculate the
> values into that column.
>
> With Arcade, you don't have to do that
> anymore; **you can do it on the fly.**
>
> Arcade will look at whatever
> columns you're sourcing from, do whatever calculations or
> string manipulations you need to do, and then return the result without the need to change your schema.

This sounds promising, but it's **not** clear what platforms the functionality pertains to.

Is it possible to create a dynamic/calculated field in **ArcGIS Pro** that is populated via an Arcade expression?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this is Pro.  Right click the layer you want to add an expression to and choose 'Configure Popup'.  There is an expression button down the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Could you please [edit] your answer to include some steps required to produce the  dynamic field on the fly?

Comment: Thanks! Is the XY only visible in some sort of popup/identify window? Or is it visible in the attribute table too? Cheers.

Comment: I believe its only in the identify/popup views unfortunately.  I know dashboards can't access it which drives me batty.